# Question related to cubic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

We have to find the minmum vale of ab if roots of the equation $x^3 -ax^2 +bx-2=0$ are positive.

I know the concept to solve for quadratic , but confused in this .

[Find m with which quadratic equation has 2 positive answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31598/find-m-with-which-quadratic-equation-has-2-positive-answers)

Comment: Question title does not match question body.

Comment: "We have to find the minmum vale of ab if roots of the equation" I don't get it, minimun of $ab$ or minimum of product of roots.

Comment: @A---B Minimum of $a \times b$(I am saying because I know source of this question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$, $q$, $r$ be the roots of the equation.

$$\begin{cases}
p+q+r &=& a \\
pq+qr+pr &=& b \\
pqr &=& 2
\end{cases}$$

Thus:

$$ab = (p+q+r)(pq+qr+pr) \ge 9\sqrt[3]{pqr}\sqrt[3]{pqqrpr} = 9pqr = 18$$

With equality when $p=q=r=\sqrt[3]2$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare see title of question